# Sharing partial views between MVC projects - Do Areas Help?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-areas

We have some partial views which need to be used in several MVC projects. Has anyone done this successfully?

Could Areas in MVC 2 be of any use ? Could a sub area project use a partial view from the parent project or the other way around?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239361/is-it-possible-to-reuse-partial-views-on-multiple-projects-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Areas is for separating One Project to different sections.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider creating either a separate library — not ideal for isolating UI logic — or a code template — very much like other Visual Studio components, e.g. starter kits, do it. In this case, you can encapsulate reusable UI components across projects.